# Is it possble to insert a formula "@NOW" in the middle of a text string?

Tags: windows, excel-formula

For example I have a financial spreadsheet that contains the header "As at August 15, 2014"

I need to have the date change on opening, but putting the formula in a separate cell will interfere with the fancy formatting of the worksheet.

"As at" followed immediately with @NOW would do the trick.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `=CONCATENATE("As at ", TEXT(NOW(),"m/d/yyyy H:MM"))`

I concatenated your text with the NOW() function.  Excel wants to turn this into a serial number rather than format it as a date when used with CONCATENATE, so I formatted the number as datetime and then turned it into text.